# Cannot calculate marginal effects in logit model

Tags: r, statistics, economics, marginal-effects, logits

I am running the following regression:

```
Model <- glm(emp ~ industry + nat_status + region + state + age + educ7 + religion + caste, 
             family=binomial(link="logit"), data=IHDS)
```

However when I use the margins command, I get the following error:

> There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)"
> Warning messages: 1: In predict.lm(object, newdata, se.fit, scale = 1,
> type = if (type ==  ... :   prediction from a rank-deficient fit may
> be misleading

Based on this error, I know that collinearity might exist. However, I do not know how to find it out and deal.

(I have tried adding each control individually)

Comment: That's a warning, not an error—your code should still run. I'm voting to have this moved to [stats.se] since it's a question about working with your data, not about the code, but they'll most likely need to see some data

Comment: I don't see any output after the command. It just shows this warning

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. Without having any of your data, a clear sense of what you're trying to do, or even the code you're running that yields the warning, there isn't much anyone can do but guess